# Arabic letters using the "Scripts for data acquisition with paper-based surveys"

Tags: arabic, questionnaire

I am designing a questionnaire with the "Scripts for data acquisition with paper-based surveys" (SDAPS) - available here: https://sdaps.org/ 
Although from version 1.1.11 released on 27.12.2015 Arabic language is available [(see here)](https://sdaps.org/NEWS/) I am not able to write all Arabic letters, and especially to copy and paste arabic text directly.
After installing sdaps and its dependences (https://sdaps.org/Download/), one could run the following minimal working example.

How to type or (even better) copy/paste Arabic letters in this setting?

```
    \documentclass[arabic, pagemark, stamp]{sdaps}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{questionnaire}

    \singlemark{How often do you use SDAPS?}{never}{daily}

  \end{questionnaire}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
I found a work around which now produces Arabic letters compiling with Lualatex. However the letters'flows goes from left to right, opposite than it should. Please see the code below:

```
      \documentclass[arabic, pagemark, stamp, final]{sdaps}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\afont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
    \usepackage[voc]{arabtex}

\begin{document}

      \begin{questionnaire}
        \begin{choicequestion}[1]{\afont{استطلاع}}
            \choiceitem{\afont{استطلاع}} \\

        \end{choicequestion}


      \end{questionnaire}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: As now added in the main text above: How to type (or even better) copy and paste arabic letters in this setting?

Comment: I see reference to pdflatex on the web site, but not to xelatex or lualatex, and you’ve loaded `inputenc`, which also suggests that you’ll be compiling with pdflatex.  In that case, the `arabtex` package is your best bet.  Have you tried it with this document class?

Comment: Actually I have tried`arabtex` and it works only outside of the "question fields". Using the `sdaps` class with the native option `arabic` produces Arabic letters from Latin characters by compiling with pdflatex. The issue is that I am unable to produce some Arabic letters (7 letters in total: ث ء ج ح خ ذ ع غ ).

Comment: `arabtex` is made for use with pdflatex and works only with its own fonts, not with any Arabic font you may choose through `fontspec`.