# Arabic Right to Left using Luatex

Tags: luatex, arabic, right-to-left

I need to write some text in arabic using Latex. It is important for me to compile the tex file using Lualatex (here I report a minimal working example, but the document class I am originally using needs Lualatex).

Everything works fine except from the fact that the text is printed in the wrong direction. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\afont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\usepackage[voc]{arabtex}
\begin{document}


        \afont{استطلاع}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want to load `babel` or `polyglossia` to deal with languages that are not English.

Comment: Not really, because using these packages my document is crashing ("sdaps" document class [https://sdaps.org/]). I am only looking for a way to invert the letters' flow under the setting proposed in the main question.

Comment: Have you tried the `arabluatex` package? It works very well, though I don’t know whether it’s compatible with “sdaps.”

Comment: This question should be merged into https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442720/arabic-letters-using-the-scripts-for-data-acquisition-with-paper-based-surveys since it clarifies that first question, and neither is complete without the other.

Comment: The original question has been updated with an example using Sdaps. However, given that few have (or want) sdaps on their machines, and also because the one posted here it is a problem in itself, I have posted a new question with a much easier example to reproduce.

Comment: You need to ping me if you want me to see your responses to my comments.  Search for `arabluatex` on this site and you’ll find examples.  The package has matured rapidly, so don’t worry about the defects in the early examples.

Comment: You are rigth Thérèse. I have a look at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not have the arabtex package. However, I suppose you are looking for something like:

```
[...]
\def\setArabic{\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT \textdir TRT}
\def\setLatin {\pagedir TLT \bodydir TLT \pardir TLT \textdir TLT}

\begin{document}

\setArabic\afont    
استطلاع
[...]
```

Comment: It should be noted that this makes sense only if you take a look at the plain luatex manual + the omega manual (https://www.hzdr.de/FKTI/latex/doc/omega/base/omega-manual.pdf)

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers.